# Sending array list from servlet back to iPhone application after executing a query

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, servlets

I have a simple iPhone application, and what I am trying to do is the following:
I have a picker view, and I have to fill it by sending a request to servlet and execute a query and send the the result back.
 
The problem is that the servlet is sending the result as a stream of bytes and I need it as an array.
The question is:
**How to send an array from servlet to the application and how to deal with it?**

Comment: I would try to send it as JSON or XML from the server

Comment: I second that. But personally I prefer JSON. Much faster and easier to decode/encode.

Comment: yeah.. i agree with you both, i read about json, and i am using it now

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether or not you control the servlet.  If you do control it you can format the response in iOS plist format and so directly read the result into a (say) NSArray.   If you don't control the servlet, well, you need to understand the format of the data it returns and format it yourself into an NSArray.

Comment: I found the solution i'll use JSON to send the response from the servlet thank you for your replay